# Getting working Quad mode SPI erase and write for MX25L25635F

Tags: c

I am trying to implement the APIs for erase and write keeping the serial flash chip (MX25L25635F) in quad mode.

I am using the command 0x20 for erase and 0x2 for write, prior to this I have used the following commands to initialize the serial flash chip to quad mode:

0X66 -> SF_RSTEN

0x99 -> SF_RST

0x35 -> Enter quad mode

Configured the SPI ASIC on controller side to 4MHz.

But the erase doesnt working for me(I don't see 0xFF when a read at particular sector address)!!!?? Kindly give inputs..

Comment: You might want to try the maker and engineering communities on stack exchange

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the sector protections each time before giving the erase command.